# Newsfeed sometimes crashed

Tags: 2016, newsfeed

I configured Mysite in SharePoint 2016, it shows the newsfeed and all employees can use it

Suddenly, the newsfeed crashed! I didn't do any changes!

It's not working until retart the wfe servers!!

I checked the distributed cache and it's started!

The log is not clear and I think restarting the servers is not option in production!

Please, guide me as your experience

Is the newsfeed stable? Can we depends on it for 1500 employees? If yes why it usually crashed and how avoid this error

Thanks

Comment: Which error do you need to avoid it? please share the error message to can help you faster!

Comment: Sorry something wrong